# Can't get current_tenant helper method inside liquid tag definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper, liquid

I am trying to access the helper method current_tenant that I have defined inside my applications controller file like this:

```
def current_tenant
    @current_tenant ||= User.find_by_alias_domain(request.host)
    @current_tenant ||= User.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain) # includes(:home).
end
helper_method :current_tenant
```

I wan to access it from inside this class. However I can't get it to work.

```
    class GetMenu < Liquid::Tag

        def initialize(tag_name, variables, tokens)

            @variables = variables.split(" ")

            @menu_object = @variables[0]
            @file_name = @variables[1]

            super
        end

        def render(context)
            #@path = Liquid::Template.file_system
            #header_file = @path.root.to_s + "/partials/#{@file_name.strip}.html.liquid"

            #content = File.read(header_file)


            content = current_tenant.theme.code_file.find_by_hierarchy_and_name('snippet', @file_name.to_s).code

            @menu ||= Menu.find_by_slug(@menu_object)

            context.merge('menu' => @menu)

            Liquid::Template.parse(content).render(context)

        end

    end

    Liquid::Template.register_tag('get_menu', GetMenu)

end
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but the the Liquid::Tag inherit in any way from ApplicationController?

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis i don't think so. AFAIK the idea is that it won't get a reference to the controller. it's supposed to be separate from the rails world.

Comment: Then how do you suppose it will know the existence of your method??? You need to make it known to the realm of the class you use it in. Either require the ApplicationController (yaiks) or place your method in a helper file (for example application_helper.rb) and require that, both in ApplicationController and your GetMenu class

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis, thank you! can you please show me how i can require  the current_tenant helper method into my Liquid tag? I have tried 100 different ways to require it but it won't work.

Comment: Write the def current_tennant in app/helpers/application_helper.rb. Don't write "helper_method :current_tenant". Go to your application controller and your class definition for GetMenu and write eg as second line "include ApplicationHelper". That should be enough

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis, the suggestion above did not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: request.host returns your server ip. What does request.subdomain give? Do some variable debugging, like logger.debug in your methods to see what puts out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the current tenant to the liquid variables in my liquidize method like so:

```
Liquid::Template.parse(layout_code).render(model_content.merge('template_content' => templ, 'settings' => current_tenant, 'theme_id' => current_tenant.theme.id), :filters => [LiquidFilters])
```

The important part is:

```
'settings' => current_tenant, 'theme_id' => current_tenant.theme.id
```

These two adds a liquid variable named settings and theme_id which contains the theme id and the current_tenant.

These varaibles can be accessed normally within the template files (liquid files) or through  `context["theme_id"]` when inside a liquid tag definition.

Full example:

```
class SnippetFile < Liquid::Tag
    class SnippetFile < Liquid::Tag
        # Include the stylesheet tag link helper
        include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

        def initialize(tag_name, variables, tokens)
            @variables = variables.split(" ")


            @default_name = @variables[0]
            @file_name = @variables[1]

            super
        end

        def render(context)

            if @file_name.present? && (context[@file_name.strip]).present? 
                content = CodeFile.find_by(hierarchy: 'snippet', name: context[@file_name.strip], theme_id: context["theme_id"])
            else
                content = CodeFile.find_by(hierarchy: 'snippet', name: @default_name, theme_id: context["theme_id"])
            end 

            Liquid::Template.parse(content.code).render(context)

        end


    end

    Liquid::Template.register_tag('snippet_file', SnippetFile)
```